# Как отправить видео в aiogram? Telegram bot/python

Tags: python, telegram, бот, aiogram

Думал такая же система как и с фото, я фото загружал на диск и брал ссылку. А с видео так не работает.

```
elif message.text == '001':
    await bot.send_video(message.chat.id, video='')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
await bot.send_video(message.chat.id, open('VideoFile.mp4', 'rb'))
```

Или

```
await bot.send_video(message.chat.id, 'video_id')
```

Или

```
await bot.send_video(message.chat.id, 'video_url')
```